# Excel - series increment wont follow the patternt

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have two excel documents one is for data and the other one is linked to data excel.

Linked excel looks like this;

='C:[data.xlsm]Operations'!A100

='C:[data.xlsm]Operations'!A103

='C:[data.xlsm]Operations'!A106

='C:[data.xlsm]Operations'!A109

In theory if I hover the cursor on my cells and use autofill (lower right corner) it should increase by "3" as pattern but it increases by "1".

How can I make it increase by "3"?
Thanks in advence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark, so it will need some adjustment to work from your side. Use the function OFFSET and ROW together with some multiplication to get the result you want. Something like this:

```
=OFFSET('C:[data.xlsm]Operations'!A100, (ROW()+1)*3)
```

The `ROW()` will give you the row number for the current line. Multiply it with 3 to get the next step. The +1 is to correct for your offset and you must pick the correct value there to get it right in your case.